# Exclude markdown from regex match

Tags: regex, markdown

RegEx is not a hobbyhorse of mine, which is why I regularly struggle with it. So far, I have always found a solution myself, but this is where I fail:

**I want matching all "\-" except inside square brackets and brackets following square brackets.**

```
\- match \- all \-
[\- match \- none \-]
[\- match \- none \-](\- match \- none \-)
(\- match \- all \-)
```

After hours of searching and trying around with uncounted variations of "lookaheads" and "lookbehinds" I am unable to achieve the wanted result.

My best attempt but with unexpected result is

```
\\\-(?!(([^\[]*])|(?!\]\()*?\)))
```

I have no idea how to exclude "](…)" without excluding "(…)", too. All attempts around that lead to the effect, inexplicable to me, that depending on the position, instead of none, some hits occur.

See: https://regexr.com/6u1v0

Maybe my approach is completely wrong, and I got stuck in it. Either way, I would appreciate a tip.

The "\-" is only one as a sample from a set of meta signs I want to modify.

Comment: how `(\- \- \-) [\-\- \-]` should work?

Comment: (\- select \- all \-) [\- select \- none \-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tool or programming language tagged, but if you want to modify the the matches for `\-` outside of the brackets, you can use a capture group to keep what you don't want to change, and then using an alternation `|` match the ones that you want to change.

Then using a programming language for example, you can check if there is a capture group 1 value. If there is, use that in the replacement.

Else use your own replacement value.

```
(\[[^][]*](?:\([^()]*\))?)|\\-
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\[[^][]*]` Match from `[...]`
  - `(?:\([^()]*\))?` Optionally match `(...)`
- `)` Close group 1
- `|` Or
- `\\-` Match `\-`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L10I4v/1).

Comment: This looks very promising – I never ever would have found this. I will test it in environment (Delphi RegEx for finding Meta signs in Markdown except in special code/links) and give feedback. Till that: Thanks a lot!

Comment: Solution is much better as I have hoped for. It solves another challenge for me as well. 

Comment: Currently, no hit is marked in group1, but all parts that are group1 hits belong to the result. In my initial euphoria, this escaped me and I realise that it is unclear to me how to completely remove this group from the result - i.e. "no hit" (figuratively speaking: no green marking in the demo).

MAYBE this is a restriction of Delphi RegEx?

Comment: @NoSi Can you check if Delphi supports PCRE? `\[[^][]*](?:\([^()]*\))?(*SKIP)(*F)|\\-` https://regex101.com/r/v9FLSq/1

Comment: I see that demo results in wanted “highlighted regions”, I can transfer this (I admit not understanding how to interpret it – but I am impressed and will analyse it), but Delphi refuses in my first test to behave like regex101. Seems as if Delphi uses PCRE but results differ. I've been looking all morning for a documentary on whether or how Delphi's TRegEx behaves differently. So far without success.

Comment: @NoSi not sure if it it helpful, but this page has more information https://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html

Comment: Thanks for all hints – I solved my challenge with a small parser to pass some additional obstacles I found meanwhile. Sometimes *straight forward* instead of sophisticated is a good idea…